Derivation for left/right pseudoinverse
I saw a derivation for the pseudoinverse as solving the problem
$$\textbf{argmin} \quad ||AB - I||_F^2$$
When argmin over all possible B, we get $A^{\dagger}=(A^T A)^{-1} A^T$. But this is "left pseudoinverse". This confuses me because $B$ is multiplied to the right of $A$. Plugging in we will get $||A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T - I||_F^2$ to be the smallest obtainable value. But if we plug in the right pseudoinverse, shouldn't it just give us $0$, assuming $m<n$ and $r=m$ (A is full row rank). I must be missing something here. I would appreciate it if someone can point it out for me.
$A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is also an interesting matrix, so-called projection matrix to the column space from the row space. How can I understand this better?

There is more here.  This might address some of your questions and might allow you to sharpen the remaining ones.
